# setting up virtual host on a LAN

Tags: internet, lan

I'm trying set up virtual host `test.com` on my LAN. I set it up on my laptop and it's working well but problem is when the others want to browse, it doesn't work!

**Note**: my laptop has ad-hoc wireless and others use it to connect to internet.
I have set up `hosts` file setting and `apache` setting and are working well.
Now what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an entry in your local `/etc/hosts` file does not affect other machines on your network, even if they're routed through your computer.